# Prove that a group is abelian if every element commutes with exactly K other elements

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $(G,*)$ be a finite group with the property that every element, aside the neutral element $e$, commutes with exactly K other elements. Alternatively speaking, the centralizer of every element is a subgroup of order K.

The conclusion is that the group $(G,*)$ is commutative.

I suppose an idea for this problem is that the center of the group, $Z(G)$, is a subgroup of every centralizer, and considering the hypothesis it would be enough to prove that a single non-identity element  $\in Z(G)$.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Consider $p$-central elements, elements of $Z(P)$ for Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|G|=n \gt 1$, then hypothesis says that for some $k$, index$[G:C_G(x)]=k$ for all $x \in G-\{e\}$. That is, the order of all conjugacy classes of non-identity elements is constant. Suppose there are $l$ conjugacy classes, outside $Cl_G(e)=\{e\}$. Then by the class-formula, $n=1+k\cdot l$. Hence $k \cdot l = n-1$, so $k | (n-1)$. But obviously also $k|n$, whence $k|gcd(n-1,n)=1$, so $k=1$, all conjugacy classes have cardinality $1$, which is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.